# Howto best setup MTLS in Azure

Tags: azure, identityserver4, mtls

I would like to host [IdentityServer4](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4) in Azure with [MTLS](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/mtls.html) configured for a specific path. How can I accomplish that by hosting the IdentityServer4 asp.net core application in an "App Service" and setting up MTLS with some kind of load-balancer: API Management service, Application Gateway, NGINX etc. What I need is requiring client certificate on a specific path and be able to set up some kind of CTL (certificate-trust-list). In other words I would like to replace the following that you accomplish with a Windows-IIS-machine and web.config:

```
<configuration>
    ...
    <location path="connect/mtls">
        <system.webServer>
            <security>
                <access sslFlags="Ssl, SslNegotiateCert, SslRequireCert" />
            </security>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
    ...
</configuration>
```

Anyone?